# How can I get a "Busy" status option in the Me Menu?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, empathy, memenu

I can control my IM status using Me Menu in Gnome Shell. The status options I have are `Available` and `Unavailable`. I'd like to control my status just I do in Empathy, but I do not have the full list of statuses:

[image: no busy status]

If I open an Empathy I'd get the `Busy` status added to list as well.

[image: has busy status]

Is this a bug or some kind of configuration I am missing? I have been using Gnome Shell 3.2 from [this repository](http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gnome3/ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have "Notifications" switch under the status list? If you disable it, your status changed to busy automatically.

It's not something that will disable all notifications like network notification or other apps notifications though. It will only disable your chat notifications.